# AJAX enviando conteúdo html pela metade

Tags: php, javascript

Estou com um  problema na sistema de publicação.

Quando vou fazer uma nova publicação e preencho todos os campos: Titulo, foto e publicação o código `var myArea2 = document.getElementById('myArea2'); var post = myArea2.innerHTML;` pega todo o elemento html dentro da `div` com **id** `myArea2`ate então ele realmente pega tudo, porem quando mando pelo `ajax` para uma outra pagina php onde pega pelo `$_POST` ele imprime o conteúdo da `myArea2` pela **metade**.

É como se o `ajax` estive-se enviando pela metade, não passa **TODO** o conteudo.

```
function enviarPost() {
            var url_s = "<?php print $url_s; ?>";

            var myArea2 = document.getElementById('myArea2');
            var post = myArea2.innerHTML;

            var now_date = document.getElementById('now_date');
            var data = now_date.innerHTML;

            var now_autor = document.getElementById('now_autor');
            var autor = now_autor.innerHTML;

            var title = $('#title_post').val();

            var result_i = document.getElementById('result_i');
            var img = result_i.innerHTML;

            if(post != '' || title != '' || img != '') {
                var dataString = 'title='+title+'&data='+data+'&autor='+autor+'&img='+img+'&post='+post+'&type=postagem';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:  url_s+"server/teste.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(tihidResponse){
                        $("#sample").html(tihidResponse);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("Todas as informações tem de estar preenchida: Titulo, imagem e texto de postagem.");
            }
        }
```

O que deveria ser uma publicação completa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Retorna somente o inicio da publicação, como se pegasse somente a **primeira tag** do conteúdo **HTML** enviado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma solução??

Tentei com type: "GET" pelo ajax, mas deu erro `414 (Request-URI Too Long)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O GET não iria funcionar, tem limites para o tamanho da string enviada.

Tente trocar isso:

```
var dataString = 'title='+title+'&data='+data+'&autor='+autor+'&img='+img+'&post='+post+'&type=postagem';
```

Por isso:

```
var dataString = { 
    title: title,
    data: data,
    autor: autor,
    img: img,
    post: post,
    type: postagem
};
```

Lógico que no seu PHP você terá que adaptar, mas em princípio irá enviar tudo.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Já tinha feito isso e realmente deu certo.